# Interaction of object-select with double quotes

Tags: object-motions

I'm trying to understand logic of text-object-selection in the presence of double qoutes. In the following lines `*` denotes cursor position, `//` denotes my comments.

```
a"b(c*d)e"f //di) deletes everything inside parens, as expected
a"b(c"*d)e"f //di) deletes everything inside parens, as expected
a"b(c"*d)e"f"g //di) does nothing
a"b"g(c"*d)e"f //di) does nothing
```

Why in the last two lines doesn't `di)` work? Why does it depend on the number of quotes outside parentheses? Is there any place where all details are described? (I didn’t find any [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs, but you need to jump around a bit. [`:h i)`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#i%29) says it's like [`[(`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5B%28), which in turn is like [`%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%25), which is affected by [`'cpoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cpoptions'):

> When the '[%](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%25)' character is not present in ['cpoptions'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cpoptions') |[cpo-%](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#cpo-%25)|, parens
>   and braces inside double quotes are ignored, unless the number of
>   parens/braces in a line is uneven and this line and the previous one
>   does not end in a backslash.  '(', '{', '[', ']', '}' and ')' are also
>   ignored (parens and braces inside single quotes).

That's what you're seeing. If you do `:set cpoptions+=%`, `di)` will consistently delete everything inside the parentheses.